# In a linux file, how to print the 20 biggest numbers in a column?

Tags: linux, bash, file, awk

I tried to use awk and I can find the biggest number in the 8th column for example. Now I need to find the 20 biggest in the column. Do I use many variables? Here's what I know how to use:

```
$ awk '$8>max{max=$8}END{print max}' my_file.txt
```

I'm new to linux and I find it difficult to find answers to problems like this in the manual, so I hope you guys can help me! Thank you! :)

Oh and an other thing: I'll need to change the permissions of all the files containing "18" inside. I tried to use something like this and it doesn't work because I'm missing something (I don't even know if it's possible to write it like that):

```
grep -r 18 | chmod -R 775
```

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: `awk '$8>max{max=$8}END{print max}'` needs to be `awk '(max=="") || ($8>max){max=$8}END{print max+0}'` to handle the rainy day cases where all values in the file are less than zero or the file is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried simply `sort -nrk8 my_file.txt | head -20`?
The n flag makes it a numeric sort, the r reverses it (largest first) and the k8 picks the 8th column.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
sort -k 8 -n -r my_file.txt | head -20
```

That is, sort using field 8 as key (`-k` stands for "key"), using numeric sort (`-n`), in reverse order (`-r`), that is, starting with the biggest numbers.  Finally, take the first 20 lines with `head`.

Comment: Wow it's perfect! I need to practice how to use simple command such as sort with pipes and everything. It helps a lot thank you kind sir :)

Also, do you think you can help me about changing the permissions of all files in my directory that contain "18" in them? I have a lot of trouble with understading how permissions work since I'm new to all this...